# Track the line in source code from the printed information in an output in Fortran

Tags: printing, fortran

I have a Fortran code which prints for instance

```
 1  2 3.56
```

I would like to comment out certain line(s) in the source code to remove the above output. However, I cannot find which line in the source code (~10k lines in total) prints it. I can add many "write" to locate the above output. Is there any trick could shows which line in source code associated with certain output?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, there is no magical backtracking from the output.

You can try to grep all `print` and `write` statements and see which look compatible with the output. If you are lucky, there won't be that many of them. Try `grep -in write *.f*` and `grep -in print *.f*`. If there are subdirectories, wrap it in `find` and `xargs`

```
find . -name "*.f*" | xargs grep -in write
```

If there are too many of them, you will have to go through the code and follow the flow of execution. 10k lines is not that much, many codes have millions.

Comment: grep has a built-in recursive search, i.e. `grep -rin write *.f*` should do the trick. note the `-r` switch or in long form `--recursive`.

Comment: Useful to know. Honestly, it is best to use some IDE search where one can click on the search results and immediately get to the line in the editor.